# List all different distribution options in VBA

Tags: vba, algorithm, excel

I have an Excel row that looks like this:

```
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Every value is one cell. What I want is to list all all different distribution options in 0.1 steps. The sum of the row is logically always 1.
So the result should look something like this:

```
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.9
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.8
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.7
...
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.8
0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.8
0.0  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.8
...
```

The result will contain hundreds of rows. I have no idea how to program this algorithm.
Thanks for every solution!

Comment: @pnuts How the listing is displayed doesn't matter. The main thing is that in the end all possibilities should be listed.

Comment: Seems to me you need more columns to do "every combination" -- like 10.

Comment: I would just loop through the first five columns, and for each one would create a loop from 0 to (1 - sum of earlier columns) step 0.1.  The last column is just 1 - sum of first five columns.  While processing the fifth column, each of the the values can be written out to a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub whatever()
Dim K As Long
K = 1
For i1 = 0 To 1 Step 0.1
    For i2 = 0 To 1 Step 0.1
        For i3 = 0 To 1 Step 0.1
            For i4 = 0 To 1 Step 0.1
                For i5 = 0 To 1 Step 0.1
                    For i6 = 0 To 1 Step 0.1
                        If Abs(i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5 + i6 - 1) < 0.001 Then
                            Cells(K, 1) = i1
                            Cells(K, 2) = i2
                            Cells(K, 3) = i3
                            Cells(K, 4) = i4
                            Cells(K, 5) = i5
                            Cells(K, 6) = i6
                            K = K + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
MsgBox K
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest putting `If` statements at every level, but there are less than 2 million iterations so it probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: @YowE3K  It runs pretty fast since there are only about 3000 worksheet "touches"

Comment: Yeah, as I said, not worth the effort.  If the OP wants to use a number larger than 1 as the total, or wants to use more columns to represent more combinations, then it may be worthwhile only doing loops if they can give rise to a potential answer - but, as currently asked, there are only 11^6 combinations to check (which is next to no time in memory) and the very small number of writes means this answer will do the job quite well.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thank you!